# taking the id value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the id value of the content below?

```
<form id="mainForm"  name="mainForm">
    <input type="radio" id="4" name="rads" value="1" checked>
    <input type="radio" id="3" name="rads" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="rads" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="rads" value="4" />
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
<span id="test"></span>

<script>
    document.mainForm.onclick = function(){
        var radVal = document.mainForm.rads.value;
        var idVal = document.getElementsById('id');
        result.innerHTML = 'You selected: '+radVal;
        test.innerHTML = 'You id: '+idVal;
    }
</script>
```

You selected value: 1
You selected id: 4

Comment: If you are not using jQuery, remove the tag. If yes, use `$(':radio[name="rads"]:checked').attr('id')`. In JS use `document.querySelector('[name="rads"]:checked').id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
document.mainForm.onclick = function(){
        var radVal = document.mainForm.rads.value;
        var idVal = document.querySelector('[name="rads"]:checked').id;
        result.innerHTML = 'You selected: '+radVal;
        test.innerHTML = 'You id: '+idVal;
    }
```

You need to select the checked element using `document.querySelector('[name="rads"]:checked')` then get the id using `.id`

Comment: Woow Thanks :) There is a problem, Why not print the data on the screen, although it is selected?  " checked  "

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can do as follow:

```
var selectedOption = $(':radio[name="rads"]:checked');
var id = $(selectedOption).attr('id');
var value = $(selectedOption).attr('value');
```

See the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/od5fot5m/

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery, this should get the value of the id for the checked input `$('input:checked').attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    var test = document.getElementById('test');


for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       result.innerHTML = 'You selected: '+ this.value;
       test.innerHTML = 'You id: '+ this.id;
    });
  }
```

That should work without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

A quick jQuery example.

```
$(function(){   // when DOM is loaded

    $('input[name="rads"]').on('click', function(){ // attaching a click event handler to the input elements with the name "rads"
        if( $(this).is(':checked') )    // If the user clicked radio, is in checked state
        {
            $('#result').text( 'You selected: ' + $(this).val() );  // display its value

            $('#test').text( 'You id: ' + $(this).attr('id') );     // display its ID attribute's name
        }
    });

});
```

Hope it will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone :) 
There is a problem, Why not print the data on the screen, although it is selected? " checked "

```
<input type="radio" id="4" name="rads" value="1" checked>
```

Coming option is selected but cannot write on the screen :(