# How to get the a href id value in javascript and depends on the id value to open relevant page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page call main.html, it includes multiple urls, those urls will go to a page called central.htm. 
The central.htm has a button which will open the destination page depends on the urls.

I read this post [taking the id value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782404/taking-the-id-value) but I don't get the idea about find the `a href` id

I apply the id in `<a href>` in main.html and use javascript in central.htm. 
However I am not sure it is possible to do it this way because I try the following code but it does not work.

*(updated code)*

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>  
        this is main.html 
    </title> 
</head>  

<body>
<style>
//making button look like a tag
button {
background: none!important;
border: none;
padding: 0!important;
color: #069;
text-decoration: underline;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<button href="https://www.mywebsite/central.htm" id="1" onclick="save(this)">First link will go to the central page first and then go to Destination A</button>
<button href="https://www.mywebsite/central.htm" id="2" onclick="save(this)">Second link will go to the central page first and then go to Destination B</button>
<button href="https://www.mywebsite/central.htm" id="3" onclick="save(this)">Thrid link will go to the central page first and then go to Destination C</button>
<button href="https://www.mywebsite/central.htm" id="4" onclick="save(this)">Fourth link will go to the central page first and then go to Destination D</button>
                                                    //^added onclick
<script>
function save(el){
  //getting id of href click
 var ids=el.getAttribute("id");
 console.log(ids);
 localStorage.clear();//clear previous data
 localStorage.setItem("ids", ids);//add data to storage
 var href=el.getAttribute("href");//get href
 console.log(href)
 window.open(href, '_blank');//open in blank page
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then all links go to the central page, the central page determines the link and then open relevant destination

*(updated code)*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>  
        this is central.htm 
    </title> 
</head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
 function openDestination() {
 if (localStorage.getItem("ids") != null) {
//get that value
 var ids= localStorage.getItem("ids");
 console.log(ids);
}
switch(ids) {
case 1:
  window.open("https://www.mywebsite/DestinationA.html");
  break;
case 2:
  window.open("https://www.mywebsite/DestinationB.html");
  break;
case 3:
 window.open("https://www.mywebsite/DestinationC.html");
  break;
case 4:
  window.open("https://www.mywebsite/DestinationD.html");
  break;
 //if none of those, close the window
default:
  window.close();
}
}
</script>

<body>
<p>Click the button and it will open the destination page</p>
<p><input id="clickMe"  onclick="openDestination()" type="button" value="click to open destination" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

After I run the code, if I click the First link button, it will go to Destination A. However if I click other link button (for example the Thrid link), it still goes to the Destination A.

Due to my website's limitation, I cannot use jQuery at the moment, so I focus on using javascript.

May I ask how can the central.htm get the value from main.html and then depends on the value to open the relevant destination page.

Reference

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button-using-javascript-jquery

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) here .i.e: Save the id of `a href` in `localStorage` and get it in other page using `getItem` and `setItem`.

Your `main.html` will look like below

```
<style>
//making button look like a tag
  button {
  background: none!important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0!important;
  color: #069;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
   }
</style>

  <button href="https://www.mywebsite/central.htm" id="1" onclick="save(this)">First link will go to the central page first and then go to Destination A</button>
  <button href="https://www.mywebsite/central.htm" id="2" onclick="save(this)">Second link will go to the central page first and then go to Destination B</button>
  <button href="https://www.mywebsite/central.htm" id="3" onclick="save(this)">Thrid link will go to the central page first and then go to Destination C</button>
  <button href="https://www.mywebsite/central.htm" id="4" onclick="save(this)">Fourth link will go to the central page first and then go to Destination D</button>
                                                        //^added onclick
  <script>
   function save(el){
      //getting id of href click
     var ids=el.getAttribute("id");
     console.log(ids);
     localStorage.clear();//clear previous data
     localStorage.setItem("ids", ids);//add data to storage
     var href=el.getAttribute("href");//get href
     console.log(href)
     window.open(href, '_blank');//open in blank page
    }

  </script>
```

Then in your `central page` do like below :

```
 function openDestination() {
if (localStorage.getItem("ids") != null) {
  //get that value
    var ids= localStorage.getItem("ids");
    console.log(ids);
  }
switch(ids) {
   case 1:
      window.open("https://www.mywebsite/DestinationA.html");
      break;
   case 2:
      window.open("https://www.mywebsite/DestinationB.html");
      break;
   case 3:
     window.open("https://www.mywebsite/DestinationC.html");
      break;
   case 4:
      window.open("https://www.mywebsite/DestinationD.html");
      break;
 //if none of those, close the window
   default:
      window.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Swati, thanks for your answer. May I ask a question about the coding please. I applied the code and run it. No matter I click which button, it only opens the DestinationA.html. I updated the code in the post, would you mind have a look and let me know how solve the issue please. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you.

Comment: Debug your code firstly check when you clicked on button what gets save in local storage i.e : if you are using Chrome -> right click ->inspect->application tab->localstorage there will be key value see there what gets save .

Comment: Also checks what console is printing .

Answer (score 1):

you can use url query.
meaning you can pass small information from page to page.
example: https://www.mywebsite/central.htm?id=1
later on the central page you can fetch this id with JS like this:

```
const url = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const id= url.get('id')
```

Personally, I think it's much easier this way and way more readable.

Comment: Hello @vlad katz, thanks for your answer. I visit this website (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and (https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/using-the-urlsearchparams-object-in-javascript-part-1-db2c066d52e6), I am a bit confuse about use `URLSearchParams`, so if get the value of url query, I need to use `console.log` to retrieve it, is it true? If so, I need to write a function to convert the value from `console.log` and apply to the button or the `a href` tag? Grateful for your advice please. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you.

Comment: there is no need to use console.log . console.log is for debugging purposes only. my answer were to show you you can use the url query mechanism. it allows to transfer data between pages for later use. you can use it and update your urls like this:  href="https://www.mywebsite/central.htm?id=1". later on the central page you can use the code above and extract the same id and use your switch statement as written.